# What to do about well-entrenched and rogue moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, specific-site

I am convinced that the moderation of the christianity.se site fails the values of Stack Exchange, certainly in spirit, but also in the letter of those values. Specifically, I am convinced that moderators *"David"* and *"Caleb"* are simply censoring any questions, answers, and comments that they simply do not like.

A year ago they banned me from that site, and I put up with the ban. But these [Machavellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Machiavelli) moderators have not changed their m.o. at all.

These moderators need moderation. They are both shameless while their actions are shameful.

How can this be discussed and evaluated in a context outside of the christianity.se site that these moderators obviously control in a nepotistic manner? The discussion needs to be drawn outside of their sphere of control.

Comment: well, i have just been banned, another year, from the christianity.se site again.  and i see lotsa downvotes (which do not change the seriousness of the situation).

Comment: If you're trying to be serious about this problem, it helps if you use proper capitalisation. I stopped reading and down voted after the first paragraph because you weren't even bothering to use correct punctuation.

Answer (score 34):

Per the [help](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/flagging)

> If you feel that there is an issue that urgently needs attention from
>   Stack Exchange staff, you can also [email us directly](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/other).

That goes to Stack Exchange employees, who have the ability to regulate moderators.  If you truly believe that Caleb and I are rogue, and that we need to be stopped, this is your recommended course of action.

Comment: I can't prove it, but I'm deeply suspicious that underneath the green makeup you've gone *rouge*.